# Django Saleor installing Dashboard 2.0 on windows

Tags: django, installation, saleor

I am trying to install [Saleor Dashboard 2.0](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-dashboard) on my Windows 10 machine for a dev environment.

So far I have

- git cloned the git clone dashboard into the same folder as the Saleor project
- Then `cd saleor/dashboard` and ran `npm i`

The instructions were not really clear on how to configure the `API_URI` to `http://localhost:8000/graphql/`. It is not in the settings.py and the instructions were not clear on where this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting environment variable on Windows somehow didn't work for me.
I changed the value of below variable in src/config.ts and it worked !!

```js
export const API_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/";
```

But ideally it should work by setting system environment variable.
Please fill free to update here if anyone is able to run it with system env variable (without changing the code).
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try the following command in the command line.(this will not work in powershell)

```
set API_URI = "http://localhost:8000/graphql/"
```